# US Visa requirements if applying in Italy as a refugee

Tags: usa, standard-visitor-visas, refugees, sierra-leone

My boyfriend and I want him to travel to the US but he needs a visa.  He has a current passport from Sierra Leone but is currently in Italy on refugee status.  Is it possible for him to apply for a travel visa to the US?

Answer (score 7):

The requirements for your boyfriend to travel to the US depend on his exact status.

If he has been **granted** refugee status he should have a [Permesso per Asilo Politico](https://www.refugee.info/italy/documents-it/for-refugee-status-holders-permesso-per-asilo-politico). This allows him to apply for a Refugee Travel Document or [Documento di viaggio](https://www.refugee.info/italy/traveling-outside-italy/travel-documents?language=en). This functions instead of a passport, and should be accepted by the US as one. Once he has this document he will have to use it and apply for a visa in order to visit the US, which he does in the normal way. He should be prepared for intense scrutiny of his application.

If he is an **applicant** for refugee status (i.e. has not yet been granted refugee status), he will have a [Permesso per Richiesta Asilo](https://www.refugee.info/italy/documents-it/for-asylum-seekers-permesso-per-richiesta-asilo). This document does **not** allow him to apply for a travel document. He is expected to remain in Italy until his application is decided. If he is appealing a negative decision then the situation is very similar to being an applicant.

Be aware that if he uses his Sierra Leone passport to travel he runs the serious risk of jeopardizing his refugee application or status.

There are also some [other situations which you can read up on here](https://www.refugee.info/italy/documents-it/permessi-di-soggiorno?language=en).

Comment: You need the document with the dark green cover showing "titolo di vaggio per stranieri" on the cover. This is your refugee travel document which you will use to apply for visas and travel to other countries.