# Travel with a UNHCR travel document to the US

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, schengen-visas, refugees, italian-residents

I was a refugee in Nigeria and was awarded a scholarship to study in Italy, in addition, I have a permit of stay for Italy.
Can I travel with the said document on educational basis for an exchange program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [US Visa requirements if applying in Italy as a refugee](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140025/us-visa-requirements-if-applying-in-italy-as-a-refugee)

Comment: Is the document actually issued by UNHCR or is it issued by Nigeria or by Italy under the refugee convention?  I believe you'll need one of the latter.

Comment: Please take pictures of the cover and the information pages of your document. Obscure personal information (name, birthdate, document number, etc) in the photo of the information page. Then attach the the two photos to the text of your question, using the "Edit" button below the text and then the "Moon and Mountains" button just above the text entry box.